# can't add custom script in overcommit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rubygems, ruby-overcommit

I'm not sure if this is something I should post in the official repository issue(I sometimes see 'question' tag there). But if you think this is the appropriate place to ask this, would be great if someone could help me out.

---

I've been trying to add a custom script in overcommit gem with no luck. 
What it says in the official document is to add lines in .overcommit.yml:

```
 PostCheckout:
  CustomScript:
    enabled: true
    required_executable: './bin/custom-script'
```

(so I've done so:)

```
PrePush:      
    customHook:
      enabled: true
      required_executable: 'custom-hook'
```

and to put the script in .git-hooks directory in the project root. So I put  this script in .git-hook dir for test:

```
#custom-hook.sh    
echo hey
```

Here's the sweet error message:

```
Hook must specify a `required_executable` or `command` that is tracked by git (i.e. is a path relative to the root of the repository) so that it can be signed
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_signer.rb:39:in `hook_path'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_signer.rb:92:in `hook_contents'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_signer.rb:88:in `signature'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_signer.rb:61:in `signature_changed?'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_loader/plugin_hook_loader.rb:51:in `select'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_loader/plugin_hook_loader.rb:51:in `modified_plugins'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_loader/plugin_hook_loader.rb:55:in `check_for_modified_plugins'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_loader/plugin_hook_loader.rb:8:in `load_hooks'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_runner.rb:195:in `load_hooks'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_runner.rb:32:in `block in run'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/interrupt_handler.rb:84:in `isolate_from_interrupts'
/Users/hiroki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/overcommit-0.34.2/lib/overcommit/hook_runner.rb:28:in `run'
.git/hooks/pre-push:79:in `<main>'
```

Obviously, it complains it can't find the executable so I'm guessing the format isn't right, but there are little information out there and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that the `custom-hook` must be relative to the root directory of your git repository. Perhaps try putting that one into `./bin/custom-hook`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steven. Unfortunately the error message didn't change with that. I also tried and putting the script in .git-hook/bin/ and it didn't work. tried just placing it on root dir, which didn't work.

Comment: I was not sure if I should have done it, but I asked in the repository's issue page and got the answer from the author. Your answer was (sort of) exactly the problem. Apparently, it is necessary to put the script in .git-hooks directory and define so in .overcommit.yml as so: `required_executable: './.git-hook/custom-script.sh`.

Comment: One, I must have tried it so somewhere in the process, but I guess I didn't add `./` part. Two at the point of posting this, I was thinking the `plugin_directory` line was already specifying that the script is in .git-hook directory, but was just doing some other stuff.